# jQuery mobile add items to ul onclick

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

So I want to select an item in a select box, and onclick of a button, **add the selected items** value and ID **to a listview** bellow.
The problem is that , I do not seem to make it look like a listview. The new item shows up in the list but looks strange. Please try it yourself
So I have the HTML for the selectbox containing products (the options of the select box are generated in jQuery dynamically from mysql. I will not get into that. Just know that the select "prodselect" contains values and ids at runtime):

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-count-theme="b" data-inset="true">
<li>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="prodselect" class="select">Choose product:</label>
        <select name="prodselect" id="prodselect">
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="appeprod" id="appeprod" value="Append product" data-icon="add" data-inline="true"/>
        </div>            
        </li>
</ul>
```

Now the part of the HTML where I want the select option to be added on click (appeprod.click)

```
<ul name="listaprod" id="listaprod" data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="e" data-count-theme="b" data-inset="true">
   <li data-role="list-divider">
        <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Selected Products</h3>
   </li>            
   <li id="products" name="products">
   </li>
</ul>
```

So I want the items to be inserted in the "products" section
In order to do that , I have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#appeprod').click(function() {
            var option = $('#prodselect').val();
            var box = document.getElementById('prodselect');
            var option2 = box.options[box.selectedIndex].text;
            $('#listaprod').append('<div data-theme="e" data-role="button">'+option2+' xxx</div>');
        });        
});
```

So basically, on button click, I want to append to #listaprod, the value selected in the #prodselect. However... As you may see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd6fC/32/) the display of the selected items look ugly... they do not look like regular jquery mobile ul list items. Am I missing some formatting somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding dynamically created content it MUST be enhanced with correct jQuery Mobile styles.

In this case this will work:

```
$('#pg_invoicedtl').trigger('pagecreate');
```

or full javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#appeprod').click(function() {
        var option = $('#prodselect').val();
        var box = document.getElementById('prodselect');
        var option2 = box.options[box.selectedIndex].text;
        $('#prodlist').append('<div data-theme="e" data-role="button" id="button_'+option2+'">'+option2+'</div>');
        $('#pg_invoicedtl').trigger('pagecreate');
    });        
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/q8wjh/1/

If you want to find more about this topic take a look at my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, you will find more then enough information about this topic.

Comment: He used it and in his case and on the other hand page events are not needed here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Gajotres. However what I wanted to achieve is this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd6fC/48/). I did it on my own but since you answered me with a similar idea I will accept your answer. For those interested in my solution check out the fiddle above. Thanks again